# Python inner function runtime complexity

Tags: python, function

Suppose I wrote a function to create another function, say like:

```
def g(x):
    #do stuff
    def h(y):
        return x*y
    return h

my_func = g(10)
for i in range(100):
    print(my_func(i))
```

In my `for` loop I am calling `my_func` a hundred times, however since I only call `g` once to create `my_func` I would expect that the `#do stuff` bit of my code will only run once at the beginning and not once every iteration of the loop.

Can anyone confirm that this is actually the case or will it run every single time inside the for loop? I couldn't find a satisfactory answer elsewhere.

Comment: `"I couldn't find a satisfactory answer"` Then what about trying yourself?  change `#do stuff` to `print('here')` and count how many times `here` is printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, if there was a line of code where `#do stuff` is, it would only run once in this example.

Tip: if you had replaced it with `print("test")` you could have checked this for yourself.